# Strapi Unit Tests: strapi.server.httpServer not working

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, strapi

I set up a test environment on a new strapi app (Typescript) following the example in the docs - https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/testing#install-test-tools. But I can't get the tests to run successfully.

This is my helper file as in the docs example:

```
const Strapi = require("@strapi/strapi");
const fs = require("fs");

let instance;

async function setupStrapi() {
  if (!instance) {
    await Strapi().load();
    instance = strapi;

    await instance.server.mount();
  }
  return instance;
}

async function cleanupStrapi() {
  const dbSettings = strapi.config.get("database.connection");

  //close server to release the db-file
  await strapi.server.httpServer.close();

  // close the connection to the database before deletion
  await strapi.db.connection.destroy();

  //delete test database after all tests have completed
  if (dbSettings && dbSettings.connection && dbSettings.connection.filename) {
    const tmpDbFile = dbSettings.connection.filename;
    if (fs.existsSync(tmpDbFile)) {
      fs.unlinkSync(tmpDbFile);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = { setupStrapi, cleanupStrapi };
```

And this is my test file:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { setupStrapi, cleanupStrapi } = require("./helpers/strapi");
const request = require("supertest");

beforeAll(async () => {
  await setupStrapi();
}, 10000);

afterAll(async () => {
  await cleanupStrapi();
}, 10000);

it("strapi is defined", () => {
  expect(strapi).toBeDefined();
});

it("should return hello world", async () => {
  await request(strapi.server.httpServer)
    .get("/api/hello")
    .expect(200) // Expect response http code 200
    .then((data) => {
      expect(data.text).toBe("Hello World!"); // expect the response text
    });
});
```

When I run this test:

The first test passed - "strapi is defined"

But the second test below fails.

```
it("should return hello world", async () => {
  await request(strapi.server.httpServer)
    .get("/api/hello")
    .expect(200) // Expect response http code 200
    .then((data) => {
      expect(data.text).toBe("Hello World!"); // expect the response text
    });
});
```

I get this error:

`expected 200 "OK", got 404 "Not Found"`

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly9rh.png)

When I replace strapi.server.httpServer with say "http://127.0.0.1:1337" which points to a running strapi app, the tests runs successfully.

Please what do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The /api/hello is a custom endpoint, you will need to implement it in a controller or just skip it.

https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/testing
[image]